# Elasticsearch: Добавление данных в индекс идет очень медленно

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Версия elasticsearch 1.4

Добавляю через [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php)

Скорость добавления около 0,5-1 секунда на 1 элемент.
Все конфиги дефолтные. Отчистил все индексы, создал новый, но это не повлияло на скорость. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите параметры сервера где установлен _elasticsearch_, а также схему документа и каким методом вы добавляете данные. У _elasticsearch_ есть пакетная обработка [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html#_bulk_indexing)

Answer (score 2):

Данные в ElasticSearch и не должны попадать молниеносно, так как при вставке необходимо поправить полнотекстовый индекс и разложить данные по шардам. Задержка появления данных для чтения в несколько секунд для ElasticSearch - обычно дело. Его задача максимально быстро отдавать результат поиска, она решается в обмен на не очень скоростную вставку данных.

Кроме того, как правильно указывает Yuiry в комментариях, если у вас значительные объемы вставляемых данных, вы можете прибегнуть к пакетной вставке при помощи bulk. В этом случае индексация будут проходить после вставки значительного объема записей (который вы сможете настроить самостоятельно, например, 1000), а не после вставки каждой отдельной записи.